# Filtering Condition in n-Table Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

We seem to have a need for a multi-table JOIN operation and I am referring to some notes from an RDBMS class that I took several years ago.  In this class the instructor graphically depicted the structure of a generic N-table JOIN query.

[image]

The figure seems to conform to examples of multi-table JOINs that I have seen but I have a question.  Does the WHERE clause, for providing filtering, necessarily have to be the last clause in the query?  Intuitively it appears that we can impose filtering conditions before a following JOIN clause, in order to properly scope the data, before we input it to the next JOIN operation.

Comment: multi-table joins best avoided?  what nonsense.  you can have poorly designed queries or efficient ones with no joins or with lots of joins.

Comment: The assertion that 'multi-table joins can be notoriously inefficient' is at best ignorant, and frankly dishonest. Well-indexed Relational databases love joins.

Comment: But to answer your question, your intuition is incorrect, as you've made an assumption about the query execution plan that isn't necessarily true. You can try writing the query both ways and then execute EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS (or whatever the equivalent is in version 8) to see what (if any) impact it has on the execution plan.

Comment: The term you are looking for is **predicate pushdown** and almost every DBMS does this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL queries consist of a sequence of clauses.  The diagram you have is rather misleading.  Common clauses -- and the order they must appear for a valid query -- are:

- `SELECT`
- `FROM`
- `WHERE`
- `GROUP BY`
- `HAVING`
- `ORDER BY`

Note that `JOIN` is **not** a clause.  It is an operator, and an operator that specifically appears only in the `FROM` clause.

So, the answer to your question is that `WHERE` clauses immediately follow the `FROM` clause.  The only "sort-of" exception is when a "window" clause is included and that is syntactically between the `FROM` and the `WHERE`.

Next, multiple table joins are often quite efficient and there is no reason whatsoever to discourage their use.  Support for joins, in fact, is one of the key design features that databases are designed around.

And finally.  What actually gets executed is not the string that you create.  A query, in fact, *describes the result set you want*.  It does not describe the processing.  SQL is a *descriptive* language, not a *procedural* language.

The SQL engine has two steps to convert your query string to an executable form (typically a directed acyclic graph).  One is to compile the query, and the second is to optimize the query.  So, where filtering actually occurs . . . that depends on what the optimizer decides.  And where it occurs has little relationship to what you think of when you think of SQL queries (DAGs don't generally have nodes called "select" or "join").

Answer (score 2):

Syntactically, the where clause has to be at the end.  But the query plan will take it into account and use it to filter wherever possible.  Note that just because you specify the from and joins in a given order doesn't mean the query will actually execute that way; it may rearrange them to whatever order it thinks will work best (unless you specify straight_join).

That said, having the where at the end does make some queries actually harder to read.